# Is there any POSIX compatibility layer for Windows x64?

Tags: windows, cygwin, posix, 64-bit, mingw

I'm trying to compile Redis for Windows x64 with no luck.

I tried different things

- Cygwin works perfectly but GCC produces only 32 bit executables
- Compling with Mingw-w64 will not work without a lot of code changes (My understanding is that MinGw does not provide POSIX compatibility for Windows)
- Microsoft Services for Unix has an outdated GCC version and requires the Unix subsystem to be installed as a dependency

Any idea?

Comment: Heh, if there was I'd be the first to use it. Cygwin has more problems than just only supporting 32bit exes.

Comment: I like to call it "VMWare" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ruling out MSU, there is no POSIX compatibility layer for Win64. Your best bet is probably on working with mingw-w64 and provide yourself fallback Win32/Win64 code for the POSIX calls you need. That's painful, of course.

Comment: FX is correct, Posix support was removed. Here is the reference: List of limitations in 64-Bit Windows (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282423)